# What is classOf[] equivalence in python?

Tags: python, reflection, types

I have imported a class in Python:

```
from mxnet.ndarray import NDArray
```

Now I want to get a `type` object *without* initializing an instance of `NDArray`.  In Scala I would do this:

```
val t = classOf[NDArray]
```

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: `NDArray` *is a type object*, presumably.

Comment: NDArray *is* a type object, no?  `from numpy import ndarray; print(type(ndarray))` tells me that it's a type object.

Comment: In general, if you want the type of an object, though, use `type`, so `type(some_object)` will return the type, i.e. the *class* of the object (also accessible through `my_object.__class__`

Comment: @Prune well, it's not from `numpy`, but yes, it's a class: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/ndarray/ndarray.py#L177

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realised that in Python there is no difference between a static object and a class/type, so it is possible to compare NDArray to a type object directly:

```
# ... v is an instance of NDArray
assert type(v) == NDArray
```